# How to do a rotation with sql query result?

Tags: mysql

I want my query result rotation by `level` field! Currently, my sql is simple group by two filed! as below show:

```
SELECT uid, level, count(uid) as counter
FROM user_log
GROUP BY uid, level;
```

`+-------+----------+---------+
|   uid |  level   | counter |
+-------+----------+---------+
|   101 | 2        | 1890    |
|   101 | 1        |  230    |
|   102 | 2        |  430    |
|   102 | 1        |  30     |
+-------+----------+---------+`

How do i make the result show as below?

`+-------+----------+---------+
|   uid |  cunter1 | counter2|
+-------+----------+---------+
|   101 |  230     | 1890    |
|   102 |  30      |  430    |
+-------+----------+---------+`

Comment: Are no. of levels fixed or they can be increased ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Yes, The level is fixed , (but, some uid may no reach some level)

Comment: The keyword you should be looking for is Pivot.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid You answer is work , but I don't know why your delete it ! Anyway Thank you so much :)

Comment: No i thought you need the count of each level but then i realize you want to pick the max value for each level so which makes it invalid that is why i deleted

Comment: @P.Salmon new skill get ! Thank you~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For only 2 levels:

```
SELECT t.uid, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.level = 1 THEN t.counter END) counter1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.level = 2 THEN t.counter END) counter2
FROM (SELECT uid, level, count(uid) as counter
        FROM user_log
       GROUP BY uid, level) t
GROUP BY t.uid
ORDER BY t.uid;
```